# If statement not working with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm setting a cookie value to 1 when a user clicks on an upload button:

```
$('.uploadbtn2').click(function(){
    $(this).val("Please wait...");
    $.cookie("upload",1,{ expires: 1, path: '/' });
    // the page then refreshes a few seconds later
});

if ($.cookie("upload")===1) {
    $('.upload-photo').show();
}
```

If the value of the cookie is equal to 1, then the popup upload div shows. But it isn't showing.

If I do this:

`alert($.cookie("upload"))` beneath, it alerts "1".

And

`$('.upload-photo').show()` outside the if statement, the div shows. Why in't it working?

Comment: So why do you think it's `1` (an integer) and not `"1"` (a string)?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise it was stored as a string?

Comment: Use `$.cookie("upload")==1` instead of `$.cookie("upload")===1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are comparing type and value both by `===`, where your cookie gives you `1` as a string.

so two options you can apply,

#### either

```
parseInt($.cookie("upload"))===1
```

#### OR

```
$.cookie("upload") == 1
```

Comment: @frosty do you understand what they do? If not - why don't you check a documentation first?

Comment: Oh type (integer vs string) and value (1) right? Does == only check the value?

Comment: right, `===` checks for value and type both, read answer carefully again.

Answer (score 2):

I would say need to cast It  to  integer  then need to do the comaparison . please try

```js
if (parseInt($.cookie("upload"))===1) {
    $('.upload-photo').show();
}
```

Comment: @MokshShah and will it?

Comment: You have a typo `pareseInt` - `parseInt`